# multiple cascading dropdown with Angular & MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Firstly apologies that post looks a bit long winded (it is just repeated code, so looks longer than it is).  I'm trying to implement a multiple level cascading dropdown - It works fine for the initial and first level (COLUMN1 & COLUMN2) but not for COLUMN3.

Here is the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetCol1()
{
using (EntityName db = new EntityName())
{

    var ret = db.TABLE_NAME.Select(x => new { x.COLUMN1 }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCol2(string col1)
{
using (EntityName db = new EntityName())
{

    var ret = db.TABLE_NAME.Where(x => x.COLUMN1 == col1).Select(x => new { x.COLUMN2 }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetCol3(string col1, string col2)
{
using (EntityName db = new EntityName())
{

    var ret = db.TABLE_NAME.Where(x => x.COLUMN1 == col1).Where(x => x.COLUMN2 == col2).Select(x => new { x.COLUMN3 }).Distinct().ToList();
    return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
}
```

Here is the JS:

```
    app.controller('DropdownPopulation', function ($scope, $http) {

    //$http service for Getting Column1  
    $http({  
        method: 'GET',  
        url: '/Data/GetCol1'  
    })
    .success(function (data) {  
        $scope.Col1Data = data;  
    });  

    //$http service for getting Column2
    $scope.GetCol2 = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Data/GetCol2',
            data: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN1: $scope.col1 })
        }).
             success(function (data) {
                 $scope.Col2Data = data;
             });
    };

    //$http service for getting Column3  
    $scope.GetCol3 = function () {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Data/GetCol3',
            data: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN1: $scope.col1, COLUMN2: $scope.col2 })
        }).
             success(function (data) {
                 $scope.Col3Data = data;
             });
    };
};
```

Finally here is the html / angular:

```
<!-- Column 1 -->
<div ng-controller="DropdownPopulation">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Column1">Column1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="Column1"
            data-ng-model="col1" id="Column1"
            data-ng-options="c.COLUMN1 as c.COLUMN1 for c in Col1Data "
            data-ng-change="GetCol2()">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Col 1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Column 2 -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Column2">Column2</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="Column2"
            data-ng-model="col2" id="Column2" 
            data-ng-options="c.COLUMN2 as c.COLUMN2 for c in Col2Data "
            data-ng-change="GetCol3()"
            data-ng-disabled="!Col1Data" >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Col 2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Column 3 -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="Column3">Column3</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <select class="form-control" name="Column3"
            data-ng-model="col3" id="Column3"
            data-ng-options="c.COLUMN3 as c.COLUMN3 for c in Col3Data"
            data-ng-disabled="!Col2Data" >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select Col 3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Col3Data is actually returning empty when there is data in the database.

If you know why Col3Data is not returning back anything then your help would be most appreciated.

Many thanks

Shaheen

Comment: did you checked by debugging, that method  `GetCol3()` been called ?

Comment: Hello Viplock, thanks for replying... yes it is being called just put an alert("Hi") and this was invoked after selecting the 2nd dropdown....... by the way, $scope.$apply(); didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found out what the problem was.  When doing the following:

```
data-ng-options="c.COLUMN1 as c.COLUMN1 for c in Col1Data
```

I was using 'values' for the first part rather than a 'key', so this was not returning data back.

changing to the following worked:

```
data-ng-options="c.COLUMN1_KEY as c.COLUMN1 for c in Col1Data
```

Viplock, thanks for your help as I found:

```
var dataToSend={ COLUMN1: $scope.col1, COLUMN2: $scope.col2 };
```

very helpful.

Regards,

Shaheen K

Answer (score 0):

If there will be some issue with digest cycle not worked , you can try using `$scope.$apply()` like 
**Update For sending data**

```
   $scope.GetCol3 = function () {
   var dataToSend={ COLUMN1: $scope.col1, COLUMN2: $scope.col2 };
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Data/GetCol3',
        data: dataToSend
    }).
         success(function (data) {
             $scope.Col3Data = data;
             $scope.$apply();
         });
};
```

Comment: Hi Viplock, thanks for your reply.  $scope.$apply(); didnt work.  I have a feeling perhaps its the way I'm passing values in data: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN1: $scope.col1, COLUMN2: $scope.col2 })?

Comment: didn't you checked what data you are receiving after final call for `$scope.Col3Data`.?

Comment: It returns [] - i've tried to just pass COLUMN2: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN2: $scope.col2 }) and it works fine... but then i start passing two values in it fails :(

Comment: to add to that... if I pass in data: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN1: $scope.col1 }) in all levels then the array returns value, if on the first level i use data: JSON.stringify({ COLUMN1: $scope.col1 }) and 2nd level JSON.stringify({ COLUMN2: $scope.col2 }) then this wont work.  if i use JSON.stringify({ COLUMN2: $scope.col2 })  from the beginning it works fine....

Comment: yes it still returns [] :(  when i only filter on column1 in all levels then [] is populated... Not sure whats wrong! :(

Comment: you can create a new class in .cs file like `public class ExampleRequest {
public string COLUMN1 {get; set;};
public string COLUMN2{get; set;};
}`

And receive data Like `public JsonResult GetCol3(ExampleRequest request)`

Comment: i think there is some issue with your data fetching from database coz if the method is been hit by the post call , then its working fine. so please check your code for fetching data from db.